# Multiple file upload results in 5 empty uploaded files

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

I have this form to upload multiple images to my gallery:

**HTML code**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="gallery.php?action=upload&folder=1">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP code**

```
$upl_count = count($_FILES['images']);
echo "Uploaded $upl_count images.";
```

No matter what I upload, $upl_count is always 5, and if I iterate over the files the following way:

**PHP code**

```
$images = $_FILES['images'];

foreach ($images as $file => $name)
{
    echo $images['type'][$file];
}
```

... the type is always empty. Nothing is echoed in the latter part. What am I missing here? Could it be an encoding problem?

Comment: What returns `var_dump($_FILES)`?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) - take especially care how to iterate those multiple files, that is where exactly the numerical index is placed (hint! hint!). - Also: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456) - that is enable error logging to the highest level, you will get undefined index warnings in your code or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for your problem [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240).

So, `$_FILES` always consists

```
Array (
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo.txt
            [1] => bar.txt
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/plain
            [1] => text/plain
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

It's not convenient! Agree? We need something more obvious like that:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => foo.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => bar.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 456
        )
)
```

To get arrays like that let's use this decorator-function:

```
function reorder_upload_files_array($file_post) {

    $file_array = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys  = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_array[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
        }
    }

    return $file_array;
}
```

Usage:

`$files = reorder_upload_files_array($_FILES)`

Comment: Yes, I'm currently at that stage of debugging. I don't know what I was thinking, this seems so much like a beginners' question.

Comment: @János Weisz: It's not a problem to be a beginner. Key point is to ask and understand how it works.